# How should I use Mocking and Fakes under .NET Core 1.1 or higher?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, microsoft-fakes

I have been using .NET Framework 4.X for years and I just switched to .NET Core . Since I want to do TDD, I want to use a mocking framework and microsoft fakes. However, it is not clear to me how to do that for .NET Core since the classical solutions are not supported.

Can someone tell me how I should use Mocking and Fakes under .NET Core 1.1?

Comment: What IDE are you using to develop .NET Core app?

Comment: VS 2017 is the ide I use but I am open for changes

Comment: did you ever find out how to use MS Fakes with Core?

Comment: Never used microsoft fakes, but we use a combination of xUnit, NSubstitute and AutoFixture in our ASP.NET Core projects and it works like a charm.. so you can check those out.

Comment: It's on their roadmap. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351467/support-microsoft-fakes-on-net-core.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install "Moq" using nuget
2. Create unit-test using NUnit or similar
3. Write something like this:

   ```
       // Arrange
       var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
       mock.Setup(repo=>repo.GetAll()).Returns(GetTestPhones());
       var controller = new HomeController(mock.Object);

       // Act
       var result = controller.Index();

       // Assert
       var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
       var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Phone>>(viewResult.Model);
       Assert.Equal(GetTestPhones().Count, model.Count());
   ```

Comment: Although this works as it's supposed to, it's not a good approach to check a collection size with Assert.Equal. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653557/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-verify-collection-size-in-xunit)

Comment: This doesn't mention Microsoft Fakes. What about Shims and Stubs?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it is about certain framework, I understood question as general mocking and faking